# How can one call a PHP function from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a piece of code, and I need to call a PHP code snippet when this function is called. Basically, it would be like this:

```
function jsFunc(){
    //do PHP stuff
}
```

I don't know if this is a trivial thing, and I'm just not getting it, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: Start with searching term `ajax`

Comment: you would need to expose this function via the PHP Api can call the endpoint from Javascript via $http.get or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that in a .js file you can organize with Ajax calls

Here great example https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp

or if you use jQuery library

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: i have a .php file

Comment: In that case above examples are right

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
function jsFunc(){
    var php_code = <?php 
    // your php code
    ?>;
}
```

EDIT: To call an object within the php code, use

```
echo $php_object
```

as suggested by noobcode.

Answer (score 0):

Run it like:-

```
function jsFunc(){
//do PHP stuff
  $pp = <?php echo "hello"; ?>;
  console.log($pp);
}
```

Now you can easily use your function where i have used echo.

Comment: This solution "works" for static data like echoing a fixed string. You have to consider that the PHP bit is only evaluated once before it is sent to the client. On the website would look like this: $pp = "hello";
This does not really help if you want to fetch more dynamic data.
For that see the other answers about AJAX on the main question.

Comment: yes. for that you need to use ajax.